# How to track usage data using client-side code in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, document-library, web-analytics, site-usage

Someone in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82742/how-to-know-which-users-viewed-which-documents-in-provider-hosted-sharepoint-201) pointed me that I could generate audit excel files using client-side code.

What I need to do is to have a piece of client-side code that will detect when someone clicks a document to view it (open) or edit it, and then store this "custom audit entry" in a on-premise database (this data will be consumed by an provider-hosted high-trust app part).

We used to use full-trust solutions in SP2010 and read the audit log, which is not possible in SP2013 apps. So we need a way to make our own "audit log".

Is there a way to do this? If so, how exactly do you add a piece of JS code to the whole site? I know you can extend some functionality with "custom UI extensions" but there's no scope for the whole site. So maybe a module? Actually, any other way that doesn't involve using full-trust code (`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`) or reading the audit log is perfect.

I'm not a SharePoint expert so please elaborate your answers.